# Formula for Google Sheets to track a rolling 6 months attendance?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can someone please help me create a formula I can use to add the points for my employees attendance issues for a rolling 6 months? I need for it to automatically adjust from the day that sheet is opened. Is that even possible? Here is as link to my google sheet for my employees attendance: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RI4UFK1H9xbGiil6NxTGVgAp9jzGzhnh0HLTF1sXYws/edit#gid=0

I have no idea how to create the formula. I have just summed up the days in each employees section as shown below:
=SUM(C7:CS7,C9:CS9,C11:CS11,C13:CS13,C15:CS15)

Comment: Stop using a spreadsheet for something it was not designed to do. You will have to put in workarounds to get around workarounds to get around workarounds to get aro... You need a database and suitable software written to handle it.

Comment: the sheet you've shared is private. Please set the sharing settings to Anyone with the link -> Editor.

Comment: Can you expand on the statement `automatically adjust from the day that sheet is opened`?!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you didn't share your sheet or [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the most impressive manner, I happen to have a similar sheet that could give you to the point where you can arrive at the answer yourself.

The specific question you asked for a rolling 6 month date range can be done with this formula:

```
=let(zMonthsBack,6,zMonth,month(now()),zYear,year(now()),
index(date(zyear,zmonth-SEQUENCE(1,zMonthsBack,0,1),1)))
```

To leverage this to count attendance, and assuming you had some format like the below screenshot, you could use this formula for each cell to populate your data. [Sample sheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ohOe_Fz-G1vPIYM4lCEMeMkJ-rCUfjlpOkoNlWR6Hwc/edit#gid=0)

```
=let(dataRng,$J2:$K,topRow,C$1,peopleAxis,$B2,
  topDate,index(year(topRow)&base(month(TopRow),10,2)), 
  allRng,filter(datarng,isnumber(CHOOSECOLS(dataRng,1))),
  zDate,CHOOSECOLS(allrng,1), zPerson,CHOOSECOLS(allrng,2),
  zMonthYear,index(Year(zDate)&base(month(zdate),10,2)),
  Index(Countifs(zPerson,peopleAxis,zMonthYEar,topdate)))
```

You won't need all of that, but I'm too lazy to strip it out or convert to a spill range (need to use byrow and by col).

[image]